# How to access the updated DOM in a React/Jest unit test?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, reactjs, jestjs

I'm experiencing with the whole React and I have a hard time clearly understanding the issue I have right now in one of my Unit Test. I committed (and pushed) my whole project so it will be easier to get all the necessary details to understand the problem.

But basically, I can't make any assertion on updated DOM elements as it keep giving me the original DOM.

Here's the Unit Test :

```
jest.unmock('../display.js');

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import sinon from 'sinon';
import TestUtils from 'react-addons-test-utils';
import EmoticonDisplay from "../display.js";

describe('Selector', () => {

var component, renderedDOM;

beforeEach(() => {
    renderComponent(true);
});

afterEach(() => {});

it('is not displayed if IsLoggedIn returns false', () => {
    expect(renderedDOM()).not.toBe(null);
    //Why do I need to re-render? If I change the value of isLoggedIn and I try to access the DOM
    //it is still the same value as before
    renderComponent(false);
    expect(renderedDOM()).toBe(null);
});

it('sets default states', () => {
    expect(component.state.stack).toEqual([]);
    expect(component.state.isAnimating).toEqual(false);
    expect(component.state.currentItem).toEqual({emote: 'none', username: ''});
    expect(TestUtils.findRenderedDOMComponentWithTag(component, 'img').src).toBe('images/none.svg');
});

it('animates a newly received emoticon', () => {
    var data = {emote:'cool', username:'swilson'};
    component.animate(data);
    expect(component.state.stack).toEqual(jasmine.objectContaining(data));
    //Same potential issue as explained earlier. Altough everything I find online tells me I should get the
    //updated DOM, I still have images/none.svg even though the code changes the source of the picture
    console.log(TestUtils.scryRenderedDOMComponentsWithTag(component, 'img')[0].src);
});

function renderComponent(isLoggedIn) {
    component = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<EmoticonDisplay isLoggedIn={ isLoggedIn } />);
    renderedDOM = () => ReactDOM.findDOMNode(component);
}
});
```

File in repo : [https://github.com/jprivard/scrum-companion/blob/9436903050697be3eb15cb31075e832980eb0b9f/app/modules/emoting/**tests**/display.test.js](https://github.com/jprivard/scrum-companion/blob/9436903050697be3eb15cb31075e832980eb0b9f/app/modules/emoting/__tests__/display.test.js)

Somehow, when I look for an answer online, I can see the exact same code running and working. And some other times, I see other ways to do it, but it seems incompatible with my current version of React/Jest/Jasmine/...

Please help :)